# Derivative product rule $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{xe^{-3x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this question in one of my textbooks and no matter what approach I take to solving it the answer is always wrong

$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{xe^{-3x}}$

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain it to me. ps, I'm new to math stack exchange, so please tell me if am asking the right kind of questions. Thanks :)

The textbook says the answer is:

$\frac{e^{-3x}}{2{\sqrt{x}}}-3{\sqrt{xe^{-3x}}}$

Comment: Huh, a downvote without a comment. Would you care to explain what's wrong? Sure, the OP hasn't shown any working but it's the OP's first post.

Comment: You mean $\frac{dy}{dx}$? Since, otherwise $x$ is a function of $y$ and it does not seem from the formula

Comment: Please edit for $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{xe^{-3x}}$. As written now it is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that by chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{xe^{-3x}}=\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x e^{-3x}}} [e^{-3x}-3xe^{-3x}]=\frac{e^{-3x} (1-3x)}{2 \sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}=\\=\frac{e^{-3x} (1-3x)}{2 \sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}\frac{\sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}{\sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}=\frac{(1-3x)\sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}{2x}$$

We can also put in that form

$$...=\frac{(1-3x)\sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}{2x}=\frac{\sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}{2x}-\frac{3x\sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}{2x}=\frac{\sqrt{e^{-3x}}}{2\sqrt x}-3\frac{\sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help man, buts It's wrong,  I've already tried this way.

Comment: @jamesjake it can be written in a different way, I update

Comment: @jamesjake check it now

Comment: I've added the textbook answer, sorry it took so long, had to learn to use mathjax.

Comment: @jamesjake yes it can be also write in that form but the solution is the same, I add this manipulation

Comment: @jamesjake it comes out a little bit different, of course there is a typo in the book, this derivative is correct!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$, then you have that

$$
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x e^{-3x}}} [e^{-3x}-3xe^{-3x}]=\frac{e^{-3x} (1-3x)}{2 \sqrt{x e^{-3x}}}
$$

Comment: Note that I given only an hint to make the asker solved himself, if you add full solution it is not good and I'm forced to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify the function to $\sqrt x \cdot e^{-1.5x}$. Then the derivative is 
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot e^{-1.5x}+\sqrt{x}e^{-1.5x}(-1.5).$$